# The semantics of arrays in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Check out the following transcript.  With all possible rigor and formality, what is going on at each step?

```
$> ls -1 #This command prints 3 items. no explanation required.
a
b
c

$> X=$(ls -1) #Capture the output (as what?  a string?)

$> Y=($(ls -1))  #Capture it again (as an array now?)

$> echo ${#X[@]} #Why is the length 1?
1

$> echo ${#Y[@]} #This works because Y is an array of the 3 items?
3

$> echo $X #Why are the linefeeds now spaces?
a b c

$> echo $Y  #Why does the array echo as its first element
a

$> for x in $X;do echo $x; done #iterate over $X
a
b
c

$> for y in $Y;do echo $y; done #iterating over y doesn't work
a

$> echo ${X[2]}  #I can loop over $X but not index into it?

$> echo ${Y[2]} #Why does this work if I can't loop over $Y?
c
```

I assume bash has well established semantics about how arrays and text variables (if that's even what they're called) work, but the user manual is not organized in an optimal fashion for someone who wants to reason about scripts based on whatever small set of underlying principles the language designer intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me preface the following with the *very* strong suggestion that you never use `ls` to populate an array. The correct code would be

```
Z=( * )
```

to create an array with each (non-hidden) file in the current directory as a distinct array element.

---

```
$> ls -1 #This command prints 3 items. no explanation required.
a
b
c
```

Correct. Each file name is printed on a separate line (although, beware of file names containing newlines; the parts before and after each newline would *appear* as separate file names.)

```
$> X=$(ls -1) #Capture the output (as what?  a string?)
```

Yes. The output of `ls` is concatenated by the command substitution into a single string using a single space to separate each line. (The command substitution would be subject to word-splitting if it weren't the right-hand side of an assignment; word-splitting will come up below.)

```
$> Y=($(ls -1))  #Capture it again (as an array now?)
```

Same as with X, but now each of the words in the result of the command substitution is treated as a separate array element. As long as none of the output lines contain any characters in the value of `IFS`, each file name is one word and will be treated as a separate array element.

```
$> echo ${#X[@]} #Why is the length 1?
1
```

`X`, not being a real array, is treated as an array with a single element, namely the value of `$X`.

```
$> echo ${#Y[@]} #This works because Y is an array of the 3 items?
3
```

Correct.

```
$> echo $X #Why are the linefeeds now spaces?
a b c
```

When `$X` is unquoted, the resulting expansion is subject to word-splitting. In this case, the newlines are simply treated the same as any other whitespace, separating the result into a sequence of words that are passed to `echo` as distinct arguments, which are then displayed separated by a single space each.

```
$> echo $Y  #Why does the array echo as its first element
a
```

For a true array, `$Y` is equivalent to `${Y[0]}`.

```
$> for x in $X;do echo $x; done #iterate over $X
a
b
c
```

This works, but has caveats.

```
$> for y in $Y;do echo $y; done #iterating over y doesn't work
a
```

See above; `$Y` only expands to the first element. You want `for y in "${Y[@]}"; do` to iterate over all the elements.

```
$> echo ${X[2]}  #I can loop over $X but not index into it?
```

Correct. `X` is not an array, but `$X` expanded to a space-separated list which the `for` loop *could* iterate over.

```
$> echo ${Y[2]} #Why does this work if I can't loop over $Y?
c
```

Indexing and iteration are two completely different things in shell. You don't actually iterate over an array; you iterate over the resulting sequence of words of a properly expanded array.